# NoMethodError using gets.chomp in Ruby

Tags: ruby, methods, undefined, nomethoderror, chomp

Can anyone help me with this simple exercise?

```
class Item
  def percents()
    self * 100
  end
end

answer = gets.chomp
puts answer.percents()
```

The result is:

```
percents.rb:7:in `<main>': undefined method `percents' for "300":String (NoMethodError)
```

Comment: Because `answer` is a `String`, not an `Item`.

Comment: Any luck with my answer?

Answer (score 2):

The variable `answer` needs to be an `Item` object in order to have the `percents` method. Or, you can remove the `percents` method from the `Item` class, and have it take in an integer:

```
def percents(int)
   int * 100
end

answer = gets.chomp
puts percents(answer)
```

This last line, however, won't do you as you would expect. Since `gets.chomp` returns a string of your input, you'll be multiplying the *string* "300" by 100, which means your output will look like this:

```
2.2.2 :026 > puts percents(answer)
300300300300300300300300300300300300300300300300300300300300300300300300300300300300300300300300300300300300300300300300300300300300300300300300300300300300300300300300300300300300300300300300300300300300300300300300300300300300300300300300300300300300300300300300300300300300300300300300300300300300
 => nil
```

You can first convert your answer to an int, using `to_i`, and then print the percent

```
2.2.2 :027 > puts percents(answer.to_i)
30000
 => nil
```

There, that looks better. Now if you'd like make your `answer` an object of class `Item`, that's a bit more tricky.

```
class Item
  def initialize(answer)
    @answer = answer
  end

  def percents
    @answer * 100
  end
end

item = Item.new(gets.chomp.to_i)
puts item.percents
```

Your output will look the same as above:

```
2.2.2 :049 > puts item.percents
30000
 => nil
```

Let me know if you have further questions, as I'm not 100% sure of the intent of the program you're trying to write. I'd recommend checking out a few Ruby tutorials like [Ruby in Twenty Minutes](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/documentation/quickstart/) or [Tutorial Point's ruby tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/) in your quest to learn Ruby. I hope this helps!